# Cannot reference a value that should have been mapped

Tags: rust

Sorry for the rudimentary question, I'm new to Rust and ink!

I get a lot of errors when I run `cargo +nightly contract test`.
I have checked [the official site](https://use.ink/datastructures/mapping/) for the usage of `ink_storage::Mapping`, but am I implementing it properly?

```
error[E0614]: type `u128` cannot be dereferenced
   --> lib.rs:102:26
    |
102 |             let token1 = *self.token1Balance.get(&caller).unwrap_or(0);
    |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[image]

repo is bellow:https://github.com/tnkshuuhei/WasmAMMcontract/lib.rs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, this is a pure-rust question. You'd better ask at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust.

Check https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html.

Remove the `*` before the expression.

`u128` is can not be dereferenced.

You only need to do that if the type is `&u128`.

Comment: Indeed, I will use it with Stackoverflow.
Anyway, I did as you advised and the error disappeared. 
Thank you very much!!